# how to get an average of unit test results in sql server db

Tags: sql, servermanager

So i'm trying to find a monthly average of unit tests my employer runs. The table consists of `test id, start date, end date, total tests, duration l, pass total , fail total and pass perc`
. I'm not sure how to pull this off (i'm a new apprentice)

I've tried a couple or suggestions :

```
SELECT AVG(a.COUNT) AS avg
from (
    select count (*) as count, month(Passed) as month
    from UnitTestRun
    group by mnth
) as a


select count(*)/count(distinct month('EndDate')) from UnitTestRun
```

Edit:
Test id: 10
Start date: 2022-02-07
End date: 2022-02-07
Total tests: 507
Dduration: 868600000
Pass total: 495
Fail total: 12
Pass perc: 97.63

Feburary average = ...%

Comment: Give some sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

By categorizing the data by month and averaging the numbers, one may determine the average number of unit tests performed each month.

```
SELECT AVG(a.count) AS avg
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, MONTH(Passed) AS month
    FROM UnitTestRun
    GROUP BY MONTH(Passed)
) AS a;
```

By averaging the pass % field in the table, the second query determines the total average pass percentage.

```
SELECT AVG(pass_perc) AS avg_pass_perc
FROM UnitTestRun;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).